# Binding WPF Progress Bar never updating

Tags: c#, wpf

During the OnPropertyChanged(), the PropertyChanged event is always NULL so the event never gets called.  What am I missing?

Here is the XML Code:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar1" Value="{Binding PBarValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
```

C# Code:

```
public PBar progress_bar = new PBar();

public class PBar : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _progress;
    public int progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _progress)
            {
                _progress = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PBarValue");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

private void Main_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar1.DataContext = progress_bar;
    progress_bar.progress=75;  // This does call the set and
                               // OnPropertyChanged but
                               // PropertyChanged is always null
                               // so it never updates UI
}
```

I am setting the "value" of the Progress Bar from another thread so this is why I need the binding.

I have tried this so many different ways at this point my head is spinning!

Comment: Irrespective of the possible multi-threading issues: You are firing the `PropertyChanged` event for property `PBarValue`, which will cause the binding to look up the value of property `PBarValue` via reflection. However, it looks like you have no property of that name. The binding has no way of knowing that you want it to retrieve the value of the `progress` property, if that is what you intend.

Comment: PBarValue is the name of the value property in the binding statement in XML.  Is this not correct?

Comment: The property name indicated in the binding must match an actual property name in your object so there is anything to bind to. Currently, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Change your xaml to bind to progress:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar1" Value="{Binding progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
```

And then change your property to raise notification on "progress" and not "PBarValue":

```
private int _progress;
public int progress
{
    get { return _progress; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _progress)
        {
            _progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("progress");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  It seems so clear now...  Sometimes you can see the forest for the trees!

Answer (score -1):

Please change your binding in the XAML from PBarValue to progress. Refer below code.

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressBar1" Value="{Binding progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"></ProgressBar>
```